# change the website URL with .htaccess from example.com/post.php?slug=test to example.com/post/test many times

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a PHP website contains three types of posts

1. normal blog Post
2. university post (descrip university)
3. scholarship post (gives info about a scholarship)

so now my website urls like:

1. example.com/university.php?post-slug=hvd
2. example.com/scholarship.php?post-slug=sch
3. example.com/new.php?post-slug=test

and I want it like

1. example.com/university/hvd
2. example.com/scholarship/sch
3. example.com/new/test

Please gimme the full .htaccess code beacause I don't know edit or coding it

my .htaccess (Only have SSL redictor ):

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW SSL_REDIRECT:asct.me
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?asct.me
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW SSL_REDIRECT:asct.me
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#rewrite for university.php
RewriteRule ^uni/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) university.php?post-slug=$1 [NC,L]
#rewrite for scholarship.php
RewriteRule ^schlr/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) scholarship.php?post-slug=$1 [NC,L]
#rewrite for new.php
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) new.php?post-slug=$1 [NC,L]
```